# Forecasting of exchange rate in matlab wıth arima model

Tags: matlab, forecasting, autoregressive-models

let us suppose that we have sample of one country's currency exchange rate rated to foreign currency, sample size is 229, here is a diagram of this sample

[image]

after analyzing time series, let us suppose conclusion is that model that  fit this time series at best level is autoregressive model with order 3 after one order difference, so I have created following

```
Mdl = arima(3,1,0);
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,y);
```

my question is how to forecast after 229  ?i know there is function forecast in matlab, I have tried different variant of this method, but I can't get which one I should use? so I need to forecast after  229, so for example I want to forecast at time index of 230?for instance after  229  for 10 days? I need little matlab code for this

**EDITED:**

```
p=forecast(Mdl,y,15)
The value of 'numPeriods' is invalid. Expected forecast horizon to be a scalar.
```

Comment: in the function `forecast` the parameter K in `forecast(sys,PastData,K)` is the number of forecast samples you want.

Comment: but this code does not work in matlab , i have tried , let me wait ,for instance this p=forecast(Mdl,y,15)
The value of 'numPeriods' is invalid. Expected forecast horizon to be a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at basic functionality in the [arima](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima-class.html) class. Once you have your model setup (ie you've estimated it) you need to run the forecast on the estimated model and not the model itself.

Try this, or whatever the periods you want.

```
forecast(EstMdl, 12)
```

I generated a random set of Y variables to show you.

```
y=rand(100,1)
Mdl = arima(3,1,0);
EstMdl=estimate(Mdl,y)
```

Looking at the Mdl variable you see the following.

```
>> Mdl

Mdl = 

    ARIMA(3,1,0) Model:
    --------------------
    Distribution: Name = 'Gaussian'
               P: 4
               D: 1
               Q: 0
        Constant: NaN
              AR: {NaN NaN NaN} at Lags [1 2 3]
             SAR: {}
              MA: {}
             SMA: {}
        Variance: NaN
```

But if you look at EstMdl

```
>> EstMdl

EstMdl = 

    ARIMA(3,1,0) Model:
    --------------------
    Distribution: Name = 'Gaussian'
               P: 4
               D: 1
               Q: 0
        Constant: -0.00644614
              AR: {-0.764413 -0.399603 -0.0888918} at Lags [1 2 3]
             SAR: {}
              MA: {}
             SMA: {}
        Variance: 0.108477
```

And finally running some code like the below shows you what the exchange rates should be.

```
    >> forecast(EstMdl, 12)

ans =

   -0.0064
   -0.0080
   -0.0107
   -0.0139
   -0.0167
   -0.0195
   -0.0224
   -0.0252
   -0.0281
   -0.0309
   -0.0338
   -0.0367
```

On a side note, you should really think if an ARIMA model is the best form for an exchange rate model.

Comment: yes thank you it is different one courses,maybe  ARCH model should work well

Comment: can i predict after  229 time  unit?i mean this forecast is after  last point of time series right

Comment: Yes. ARIMA forecasts will be from the end of the time series. I suggest you look at the [Nasdaq Example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.forecast.html#examples) on Matlab help for a more robust example.